# Styled Checkbox Label won't check

Tags: html, css, checkbox, label

I'm having this issue with a styled checkbox/label combination, and it seems that the label won't check when I click on it. There is a button on the page to "select all" the checkboxes, and that works, but clicking normally nothing happens.

Code

```
<td><div class="checkbox"><input class="check" type="checkbox"><label class="checklabel" for="check"></div></td>

.checkbox {
        margin: 3px auto;
        width: 25px;
        position: relative;
}
.checklabel {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: #eee;
        border:1px solid #ddd;
}
.checkbox label:after {
        opacity: 0.2;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 9px;
        height: 5px;
        background: transparent;
        top: 6px;
        left: 7px;
        border: 3px solid #333;
        border-top: none;
        border-right: none;

        transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.checklabel:hover::after {
        opacity: .5;
}
.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
        opacity: 1;
}
```

EDIT:

Alright, so thanks so much, the `for` tag needing an ID fixed the issue. Now the problem is that there are multiple checkboxes on the page, but only the first one is getting selected even if you click on any of them. Any ideas with that?

Comment: you should mark an answer as accepted and create a new question instead of edit this one.

Comment: @dippas Alright, I'll do that. Thanks. Can't accept your answer for another few minutes though. Will do when I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not closing `label` tag and you need to give an `id` with same name as  the `for` attribute

```css
.checkbox {
  margin: 3px auto;
  width: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.checklabel {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.checkbox label:after {
  opacity: 0.2;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 9px;
  height: 5px;
  background: transparent;
  top: 6px;
  left: 7px;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.checklabel:hover::after {
  opacity: .5;
}

.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
<input id="check" class="check" type="checkbox"><label class="checklabel" for="check"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work or is it supposed to be like that.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` attribute in the label must be the checkbox's id. As your checkbox id isn't `check` it doesn't work.

```
<td><div class="checkbox"><input id="check" class="check" type="checkbox"><label class="checklabel" for="check"></label></div></td>
```

Also you can just encapsule the checkbox in the label without having to set the `for` attribute.

```
<td><div class="checkbox"><label class="checklabel"><input class="check" type="checkbox"></label></div></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the label tag and the input needs an id to correspondwith the label.

```
<div class="checkbox"><input class="check" type="checkbox" id="check" /><label class="checklabel" for="check"></label></div>
```

Edit: typo